# How I could make a table content from user inputs with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, user-input

I want to make a table that contains user inputs and classified them I did initialize this code but the  contents keep show aside if you made many inputs and display in a weird way  I tried so many other ways and the same problem happens help, please

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#btn").click(function(){

            $("#tbody").append("<tr></tr>");
            $("tr").append("<td></td>");
            $("td").append($("#txt").val());

            $("#tbody").append("<tr></tr>");
            $("tr").append("<td></td>");
            $("td").append($("#txt2").val());


            $("#tbody").append("<tr></tr>");
            $("tr").append("<td></td>");
            $("td").append($("#txt3").val());

});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="btn">add table element</button>
<br>
<br>

<input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Nom"  >
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt2" placeholder="Prenom">
<br>
<br>
<input type="Number" id="txt3" placeholder="Nº dossier">
<br>
<br>


<table border="1">
 
<thead>
<th>Nom</th>
<th>Prenom</th>
<th>Nº dossier</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('#add').on('click',function(){
      
      var field1=$('#field1').val();
      var field2=$('#field2').val();
      var field3=$('#field3').val();
      
      var data=`<tr><td>`+field1+`</td>`+
                      `<td>`+field2+`</td>`+
                      `<td>`+field3+`</td></tr>`;
      $('#table').append(data);
      
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' id='field1' />
<input type='text' id='field2' />
<input type='text' id='field3' />
<button id='add' >Add </button>


<table id='table'>
<tr>
  <th>Field 1 </th>
  <th>Field 2 </th>
  <th>Field 3 </th>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jquery selector `$("tr")` or `$("td")`, you select all(not last) `tr` and `td` tags respectively. If you want to add `tr` with three `td` inside with data, you should create 1 tr, 3 td, append data in each td, then append each td in tr, then append tr on page. And you should add id for tbody tag for selecting like `#tbody` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#btn").click(function(){

    var raw = $('<tr></tr>');
    var ceil1 = $('<td></td>').append($("#txt").val());
    var ceil2 = $('<td></td>').append($("#txt2").val());
    var ceil3 = $('<td></td>').append($("#txt3").val());

    raw.append(ceil1).append(ceil2).append(ceil3);

    $('#tbody').append(raw);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="btn">add table element</button>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Nom"  >
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" placeholder="Prenom">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="Number" id="txt3" placeholder="Nº dossier">
  <br>
  <br>

  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prenom</th>
      <th>Nº dossier</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand your question, but I guess you want to add your form data to your table. I would do it this way. Notice that I have added an id to your table. I am also using backticks ` not regular apostrophe ' signs to get the values from the form.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<button id="btn">add table element</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Nom">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" placeholder="Prenom">
  <br><br>
  <input type="Number" id="txt3" placeholder="Nº dossier">
  <br><br>

<table id="myTable" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prenom</th>
    <th>Nº dossier</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function () {

    $("#myTable").append(`
      <tr>
        <td>${$("#txt").val()}</td>
        <td>${$("#txt2").val()}</td>
        <td>${$("#txt3").val()}</td>
      </tr>`)
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```